# BOINC launches on Ubuntu startup. How to remove program from startup bash script directly?

Tags: ubuntu, startup

I have installed BOINC platform. And now it launches on OS startup. Can't find it in `Startup Applications Preferences`. Please help me to prevent it from start using command line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/731668

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sudo systemctl disable boinc-client` to stop it. If it still starts up on boot, use `sudo systemctl mask boinc-client`, which should entirely prevent it from starting (you can't start it manually then either, which is...not ideal).